# Como validar ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, validação, combobox

Tenho um `Form` de cadastro no qual possui alguns campos `TextBox` e `ComboBox`, quero que meu código  permita ao usuário efetuar o cadastro somente quando todos os campos forem preenchidos, porém está validando apenas as `TextBox`, assim permitindo a efetuação do cadastro sem selecionar uma opção no `ComboBox`. Segue o código:

```
   private void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSerie.Text == string.Empty) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, selecione uma série!", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtSerie.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O CADASTRO FOI REALIZADO COM SUCESSO!", "Novo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                LimpaTela();
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode checar a propriedade `.SelectedIndex` da `ComboBox`. Ela retorna um `int` que representa a posição(Indice) do Item na `ComboBox`.

Acrescente isso:

```
else if (suaComboBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
{
    //--> seu código para tratar           
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, deu certo! :)